# Google App Engine: Filter-related NoClassDefFoundError in Deployed Version

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing using Google App Engine (1.8.7) in Java. I have the following filter in my web.xml file...

```
<filter>
     <filter-name>MultiReadRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.fitc.general.MultiReadRequestFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultiReadRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For info the filter wraps the For info the file allows multiply reads to HttpRequest by caching the request :

```
 @Override
 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      /* wrap the request in order to read the inputstream multiple times
      MultiReadHttpServletRequest multiReadRequest = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) request);
     chain.doFilter(multiReadRequest, response);
 }
```

Anyway. Everything works swimmingly on my `localhost` dev server but when I deploy to GAE something breaks. I get the following error in my GAE log:

```
Error for /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class com.fitc.general.MultiReadHttpServletRequest at
    com.fitc.general.MultiReadRequestFilter.doFilter(MultiReadRequestFilter.java:23)
        at
    org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at
    com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    (...as so on!)
```

Does anyone know what might be happening to cause this? I have a couple of other filters and they run fine when deployed. I wondered whether perhaps it was that these used jars so I made a jar of my `MultiReadHttpServletRequest` class and stuck it on buildpath and `lib/` directory... no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone else has a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` issue on GAE, its worth checking that GAE supports that 'whatevers' you import in your code. I was using `java.util.ResourceBundle` for something or other, which is not supported by GAE...but would of course work on local machine running with Java JDK.

So nought to do with filters or HttpRequests at all. Who knew eh? Glad I did not waste a day fiddling with it huh! Hummm?

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is one of the most misleading throwables in the Java class library. If it says "Could not initialize class", the real problem is that an exception was thrown in the static initializer of the class named! Major pain. That is why some people recommend not doing anything non-trivial in static initializers.

Comment: P.S. you should accept your own answer, so that this question doesn't show up as unanswered in the lists of questions.